# Custom Database Table and foreach

Tags: customization, database, php, table

I have just created a custom database table and would now like to output every inserted row from it into a predefined format using a foreach statement.

Some guidance in this matter would be great.

Thanks,
Ashley

Comment: Are you using WordPress?

Comment: Yes I am. Hope you can help

Comment: How did you create the table? Manually?

Comment: I followed this tutorial: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins

Comment: Basically the table is filled with content when the theme is activated. (I modified the tutorial to work with themes using switch_theme

Comment: Okay... so you're familiar with hooks and `$wpdb`. Check this reference, it'll explain a lot... http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb . You can always come back here if stuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Rutwick Gangurde, I found out how to do it.

```
<?php
$mylistitems = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_mytable");

foreach ( $mylistitems as $mylistitem ) 
{
echo $currency->somefield;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have table that's prefixed with the WordPress prefix (even if it's not the default one), and the table is called `table`. Then the following code should select everything, and allow you to go through each row. In this example, it goes through each row and outputs the content of the field `foobar`.

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."table");
foreach ( $results as $row ) 
{
    echo $row->foobar;
};
```

See the [Codex page on `$wdpb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Answer (score 0):

Use the wpdb class with something like:

```
global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM [custom table name] WHERE key = 'value'");

foreach( $results as $r ) {

    echo $r->field_name;

}
```